# Is the arcsin trasformation useful to reduce multicollinearity?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, variance-inflation-factor

I would like to use a GLM but, testing multicollinearity using the VIF parameter, I obtained higher correlation among independent variables (expressed as percentages). Is the arcsin trasformation useful to reduce multicollinearity?

Comment: I don't see how, it might, but not in a helpful way. It's a monotonic transformation, so you might lose some linear dependency but you still have non-independent variables.   I thought arcsin was used to transform proportion data (0, 1) to ($-\inf, \inf$).   There are specific techniques for dimension reduction if you really feel you need them.

Comment: Dear Dr. Hewson, thanks for the information provided. Sincerely

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you intend to transform and why you believe that could solve a multicollinearity issue?

Comment: Dear Dr. Roland, I didn't believe that it could have solved the problem, but I desired to know if it could have been a suitable solution. Speaking with other collegues, they told be that such method were frequently used, expecially in the past. Anyway, based on what I read, I had serious doubt about it. So, I performed further researches and, in fact, It seems that is not an adequate method. Thanks for your time. Sincerely